# make keeps running a rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The working example below always runs `touch fileA` with each run of `make`. How can I stop this?

```
all: analysis.txt

analysis.txt: countries
    touch $@

countries: usa.txt mexico.txt

$(countries): %.txt

%.txt:
    echo "bash ./cityGenerator $*" > $@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `analysis.txt` depends on `countries` which is considered as a file, but such file is never created, hence the rule is always run. You can find out by the debug output:

```
$ make -dr
...
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'analysis.txt'.
   Prerequisite 'countries' of target 'analysis.txt' does not exist.
  Must remake target 'analysis.txt'.
touch analysis.txt
...
```

It seems like you are treating `countries` as a variable, so maybe this could be reworked:

```
$ cat Makefile
all: analysis.txt

countries := usa.txt mexico.txt

analysis.txt: $(countries)
        touch $@

%.txt:
        echo "bash ./cityGenerator $*" > $@
```

Now there is no `countries` file considered and `make` behaves as expected:

```
$ make
echo "bash ./cityGenerator usa" > usa.txt
echo "bash ./cityGenerator mexico" > mexico.txt
touch analysis.txt

$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Answer (score 3):

`fileA` depends on `workflowB`.  So as long as `workflowB` is out of date, `fileA` will be out of date and the touch will be run.

`workflowB`, as shown here, is marked `.PHONY` so it will ALWAYS be considered out of date by make, so `fileA` will ALWAYS be rebuilt.

Even if it weren't `.PHONY`, there is no rule to create a file named `workflowB` so it would still always be out of date.

As for how you can stop it, that depends entirely on what these things do which you haven't told us, and why you structured `workflowB` that way which you also haven't told us.

One way to solve it would be to remove the `.PHONY` and give `workflowB` a recipe that touches a file, then it would be up to date.:

```
workflowB: workflowB_files
        touch $@
```

But of course, that might defeat the purpose of this (which, again, you haven't told us).

Comment: I have revised the example per your guidance.

Comment: You still have the same problem, but now with a prerequisite named `countries`.  It doesn't exist, so any target that depends on it can never be up to date.  See the answer from @raspy.